# Recreate a Flex 3 scene

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, state

Does anyone know how i can reset/reinitialize a state in flex 3?

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="Scene1">
        <mx:AddChild>
            <Scenes:Scene1 id="scene1"></Scenes:Scene1>
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>
    <mx:State name="Scene2">
        <mx:AddChild>
            <Scenes:Scene2 id="scene2" models="{models}"></Scenes:Scene2>
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>
</mx:states>
```

And every time i go from 1 to 2 or 2 to 1, I wan't to recreate the entire State.

Comment: I "solved" this by adding a listener that listens for changes in one of the variables, then recreates the state.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain this is what you are looking for, but this code will render the states you have defined above:

```
// this shows Scene1
this.currentState = "Scene1";

// this shows Scene2
this.currentState = "Scene2";
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: No, that just changes the state (and creates it the first time it's selected). I wan't to recreate it the next time i change states.

Comment: By recreate, I guess you mean clear out any data entered by the user? If that's the case, the only way I know is to write code to clear it all out after setting the currentState ~ perhaps someone else knows a quicker way.

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking about doing that, but it would be so much easier and so much less work if there was another way.

Thanks for your answers!